# Magento 1.8 cant upgrade to 1.9

Tags: magento, curl, upgrade

Currently using Magento version 1.8.1.0, i am trying to upgrade to the latest version - ver 1.9.0.1 - Added May 16, 2014. 
Cache is disabled, Compilation is disabled. When i check for upgrades in Magento Connect it shows the same 1.8 version files and says i allready have the latest version.

And even if I try to use community/mage_all_latest I get the same result. I wasnt able to find anything that could help me so i am asking for any clue that might point me to a way to fix this.

Logging shows this:

```
2014-06-16T22:24:59+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set  in /home/package/public_html/xxx/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php on line 529

2014-06-16T22:25:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: is_file() [<a href='function.is-file'>function.is-file</a>]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(var/cookie) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/package:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)  in /home/magentop/public_html/xxx/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php on line 157
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.0.1 from 1.8.1.0

1) take a backup of current database and current 1.8.1.0 code.
2) download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3) remove all folders and files from your 1.8.1.0 code (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.
4) now from your 1.8.1.0 merge your following folders into the 1.9
    - Community app/code/community
    - Local app/code/local
    - Media 
    - your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/<ur theme> or app/design/frontend/<your package>)
    - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
    - copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/
    - any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
    - copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.8.1.0) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
    - custom js files if any from app/js/.
5) now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6) now check the site.it done.
```